# Comment lines with duplicate pattern in a file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

im going to reformulate the question(erasing the first one, as i can't answer :-( ):

i have a hobocopy bat script that apart from doing the incremental backup, produces a file for restore the backup, with this kind of lines:

```
xcopy "w:\path\to\file\2015-08-13__11_56_INCREMENTAL\file" "E:\path\to file\file*" /E /C /I /Q /R /Y /X
```

the first path changes every time i excuted the inc. backup, but i want to comment out the lines that repeat the second path, except the last of them.(to avoid copying and overwriting the file.

This is the part of the bat where i populate the restore.bat:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%i in ( 'dir /A-D /s /B /W "!ruta_bkp!"') do (    
    set "str=%%i*"
    set str=!str:_INCREMENTAL\=_INCREMENTAL!
    set str=!str:%rutadest%=!
    set str=!str:%times%=!      
    set def=!ruta:~0,3!!str!

    echo xcopy "%%i" "!def!" /E /C /I /Q /R /Y /X >> "!direc!\TO_RESTORE.bat"   
)
```

As you see, i write a line for every file in the dir commnad, but, AS THIS FILE HAS LINES OF OLDER EXECUTIONS, i want to comment out the lines that repeat the second path... so it will be something like:

```
for line in TO_RESTORE_BAT{
    findstr pattern(!def!) --> if found --> REM line
}
 echo xcopy %%i !def! >> TO_RESTORE_BAT
```

or something like that...

Thanks.

Comment: Is the last line not commented because the right side is missing a `5, so it is not a true duplicate pattern?

Comment: Never mind, that can't be it, because the commented `44444PP444444` line is also unbalanced. You need to be more precise as to exactly what pattern(s) get commented.

Comment: excuse me, the file was only an e.g. just for show how the script should work and of course the real pattern are not  'PP', like in the e.g., but a local path.... im going to reformulate my question down...

Comment: Now it begins to make sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$NewFile = @()
$TextFile = Get-Content c:\test.txt
$TextFile | % {
    if ($_ -match "\D+")
    {
    $NewFile += "REM $_"
    }
    else
    {
    $NewFile += $_
    }
}
$NewFile | Out-File c:\test.txt
```

*Of course this is in case the duplicate pattern is letter chars like your example otherwise you need to change the regex `"\D+"` which means non digits to something else

Check this: http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/qAxK/appendix-b-regular-expression-reference

Comment: Thanks Avshalom, the script works, but it commnets also the last line with the pattern....anyway i make an error formulating the question, so im going to do it again...